# Rails for Zombie Level 5, Challenge 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-for-zombies

I'm not actually sure what they are asking me to do.

This is the question:

Create a resources route for zombies

Resources:

```
class ZombiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => 'success', :layout => nil
  end
end
```

My code:

```
RailsForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'zombie' => 'Zombies#index'
end
```

I'm not sure what it means by a 'resources route'; I at first assumed it wanted me to set a parameter in the url to match, but there is nothing to match to in the controller. Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Match" is for matching URL strings to a controller/action.

A resource route looks like this:

resources :photos

You use the "plural" of the word.  What that does is gives you the 7 "rest" urls for photos. New, create, edit, update, show, destroy and index.

But you need a table in your database called Photos for this to work.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I knew what this was, but I didn't match the word to the action in my head!

Comment: Kudos for posting the question here instead of taking a points hit with a clue ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Original Hint #1

> Give :zombies a resources route.

## Original Hint #2

A possible correct answer is:

```
TwitterForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :zombies
end
```